# Blank bibliography page getting created

Tags: bibliographies

I am writing an article in Lyx using a latex template. For some reason, I am getting a blank bibliography page (in addition to the actual bibliography) when I compile it. I deleted everything in the article except the bibliography part and I am still getting the extra page. Of course, I could just remove it after compiling, but it's annoying to have to do it for every draft.

I am able to reproduce the error with a bib file that contains the following text only:

```
    @book{Eisenbud,

Author = {David Eisenbud},

Publisher = {Spring-Verlag},

Title = {Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry},

Year = {1995}}
```

The following is the code.

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{introduction}[theorem]{Introduction}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\include{header}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}        % Numbers theorems "x.y" where x
                                        % is the section number, y is the
                                        % theorem number

%\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{theorem}}

%\makeatletter                          % This sequence of commands will
%\let\c@equation\c@theorem              % incorporate equation numbering
%\makeatother                           % into the theorem numbering scheme

%\renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\roman{enumi})}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%This command creates a box marked ``To Do'' around text.
%To use type \todo{  insert text here  }.

\newcommand{\todo}[1]{\vspace{5 mm}\par \noindent
\marginpar{\textsc{ToDo}}
\framebox{\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95 \textwidth}
\tt #1 \end{minipage}}\vspace{5 mm}\par}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}\nocite{*}

\bibliography{thesisref}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’m not sure if i understand what you mean. Do you get an empty bibliography (no entries) or do you get the desired bibliography but an additional blank page at it’s end?

Comment: @Tobi: I get the desired bibiliography with the desired entried. However, there is a page before the actual bibliography with the word "Bibliography" in the center of the page and nothing else.

Comment: OK. Then it would be great if you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (please include a sample bib via `filecontens`). In your above code I can’t finde the cause (btw. the `\makeatother` before loading `babel` can’t be right in this place since it should be used together with `\makeatother` …).

Comment: @Tobi: Thanks for your help. I am not sure what "filecontens". I could not find it mentioned in the question you link either. As for the code, I haven't written it myself. I wrote the document in Lyx and exported it to latex, so I am not sure \makeatother does here. I have included a sample .bib file in my question above.

Comment: [Here](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) you can find something about `filecontents` (it’s the third link in the above mentioned answer …). As Gonzalo said it’s nearly not possible to find the error with the given scrap of code.

Answer (score 3):

From the code you posted, it can be inferred that you are using a document class that uses chapters. Normally, `\chapter` and `\chapter*` internally issue a `\cleardoublepage` command to ensure that every chapter starts on an odd numbered page. If the last page before the bibliography was odd numbered, then the `\chapter*` used to typeset the bibliography heading will produce a blank page. To avoid this, you can locally redefine `\cleardoublepage` to behave as `\clearpage`, by using

```
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{thesisref}
\endgroup
```

If you want to allow *all* chapters starting in any new page (whether it is odd or even), you can use the `openany` class option. Assuming the `book` class is used, then you can say:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Gonzalo. I made both changes, both one at a time and together and I am still getting the blank page.

Comment: @B.M.: then we'll need a *complete* sample of your code. The document class used is missing in the code you posted.

Comment: I have the same problem with the article class :( and don't know how to solve it either. It seems there are more people with the same problem: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=317