# \include-d chapter and \refsection leads to blank pages in book-based classes

Tags: biblatex, page-breaking

The MWE is pretty much as small as I can get it and replicate the problem.  I `\include` chapters of my thesis (using a template based on `book`}.  Immediately after the last chapter I have a [list of publications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179777/28808).  But if the chapter finishes on an even page, rather than the publications list starting on the next odd page, I get a blank odd, a blank even, than the publications list. You can guess where it finishes now I've written the last chapter!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage[
    firstinits=true,
    maxbibnames=100,
    style=numeric-comp,
    sortcites=true,
    sorting=none,
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,
    natbib
]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{me_poster,
    title="a poster",
    author="Me",
    keywords="me",
    year=2013
}
@article{me_article,
    title="a journal article",
    author="Me",
    journal="journal of stuff",
    year="2012",
    keywords="me"
}
@article{AuthorA_article,
    title="An Article",
    journal ="journal of applied stuff",
    author="Author, A",
    year="1999"
}
@book{AuthorB_book,
    title="A book",
    author="Author, B",
    year="1666"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname_c1.tex}
        \chapter{Body}
        Some people said some stuff.\supercite{AuthorA_article}

        This is on an odd page.\supercite{AuthorB_book}
        \clearpage
        \dots and this is on an even page.
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\include{\jobname_c1}%
\begin{refsection}%
    \begingroup
        \defbibenvironment{myrefs}
              {\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{}\list{}{%
                 \leftmargin\bibhang
                 \itemindent-\leftmargin
                 \itemsep\bibitemsep
                 \parsep\bibparsep}}
              {\endlist}
              {\item}
              \nocite{*}%
        \printbibliography[sorting=ynt,omitnumbers=true,env=myrefs,keyword=me,title={Publications and presentations},heading=bibintoc]%     
    \endgroup%
\end{refsection}%       
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code -- 5 pages overlapped]
Sorry about the big image - if I make it smaller it's not clear.

Notes:

- I've left showkeys on as it shows where the `\refsection` starts
- I think this has something to do with the fact that `\refsection` uses a chapter in `book`-based classes, if I use `article` (and make the `\chapter` in the include into a `\section`) the problem goes away.
- I've seen the answer at [Blank bibliography page getting created](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29573/28808), but that makes the publications list start on page 4, not 3, where it should go (unsurprisingly).
- It feels like an *extra* `\clear(double)page` is being issued somewhere within the `\refsection` but I don't know where.

Comment: The blank pages go if you remove `showkeys`  I'd blame the author of that package if I were you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have heard the author of `showkeys` is a very peculiar fellow... ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if only they were all that easy.  The "final" package option (or class option) works as well.  I seem to remember it tells the package to do nothing at all. Presumably the presence of something in the body of the page at the `\refsection` causes the page to not be empty when `\printbibliography` starts a new chapter.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blank pages go if you remove `showkeys` (or disable it with `final`)

The package tries to find "safe" places to print its markers but it is hard especially in generated content as here where you can not directly control the label. Two `\cleardoublepage` in a row normally do not generate multiple blank pages but here the label display is causing the page not to be blank so a second `\cleardoublepage` is throwing two extra pages.